# How to pass spring boot argument to tomcat deployment?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project with packaging war stated in the pom file.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>   
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

With a maven clean package command I'm able to build the war file. Next step is to launch the war file with

```
java -jar <artifactId>.war --spring.config.name=application-<profile>
```

Important is that I pass an argument (spring.config.name) which is working fine. But my question is how can I pass this argument while deploying this war in a tomcat environment? I copy the war in the webapps folder of tomcat. But where I'm able to pass the mentioned argument?

**Edit** for more clarification: I'm not searching for a solution by setting a system variable or something. A proper solution from my point of view would be a configuration over a maven profile. For example if I build my project with

```
mvn clean package -P<profile>
```

the argument is passed to the appropriate location in spring boot.

**Edit 2**: My ServletInitializer extends from SpringBootServletInitializer which extends from WebApplicationInitializer

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

And my Application class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the class which implements WebApplicationInitializer

Comment: @ShivamSinha I added the requested class :) Thanks in advance

Comment: Just in case if anyone still looking for answer on this please have look at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53297330/1131967

Answer (score 0):

You can pass context parameters to the servlet context with a context.xml. Add this as context.xml next to your pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Context>
<Context>
    <Parameter
        name="spring.profiles.active"
        value="${spring.profiles.active}"
        override="false" />
</Context>
```

Then use the maven-war-plugin like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <containerConfigXML>context.xml</containerConfigXML>
        <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then use a profile to set the spring.profiles.active property.
Spring actually will pick these up without config but somehow Spring Boot does not. For it to work in Spring Boot you can use something like this:

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
            SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        String activeProfiles =
                servletContext.getInitParameter("spring.profiles.active");
        if (activeProfiles != null) {
            builder.profiles(activeProfiles.split(","));
        }
        return builder.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```